# inequality about $I=\int_{2012}^{3012}\sqrt[3]{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, radicals

> Consider
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>   & L=\sqrt[3]{2012}+\sqrt[3]{2013}+\ldots +\sqrt[3]{3011} \\ 
>  & R=\sqrt[3]{2013}+\sqrt[3]{2014}+\ldots +\sqrt[3]{3012} \\ 
> \end{align}\
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> I=\int_{2012}^{3012}\sqrt[3]{x}\,dx
> $$
>   then which of the following holds?
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>   & \text{(a)  } L+R<2I\qquad  \text{(b)  }L+R>2I \\ 
>  & \text{(c)  }L+R=2I\qquad  \text{(d)  }\sqrt{LR}=I \\ 
> \end{align}
> $$

I have verified numerically that $\text{(a)}$ is indeed the answer, but I couldn't  verify it analytically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
L+R = \sum_{n = 2012}^{3011} (\sqrt[3]{n}+\sqrt[3]{n+1})
$$
and
$$
\int_{2012}^{3012}\sqrt[3]{x}dx = \sum_{n = 2012}^{3011}\int_n^{n+1}\sqrt[3]{x}dx
$$
So all you have to do is prove that
$$
\sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[3]{n+1} < 2\int_n^{n+1}\sqrt[3]{x}dx
$$
for any positive integer $n$. Can you manage that?